# Find out whether a URL is broken?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a URL that should contain a video:

http://img.epictv.compodcasts/Surf_Report_Tahiti_Take_2_podcast.mp4

But, it seems to be broken (the resource is not available). Is it possible to know that it is broken programatically?

Comment: Broken means a 404 error or something else?

Comment: @Luda no he means what you mean with "broken". You mean if the file isn't available, or the server, or no dns entry, or whatever.

Comment: Yes, @NSAddict is right.

Comment: Ps you forgot a slash: http://img.epictv.com/podcasts/Surf_Report_Tahiti_Take_2_podcast.mp4

Comment: You probably mean whenever the resource is not available

Comment: Voted to close because you are missing the code on how you load the URL and how you are handle error. This is more an give me de code please kind of question.

Comment: Take a look at `AFNetworking`. You can check for the availability of a server or a specific file: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Or NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection, for a more lightweight solution

Comment: @NSAddict If I use this, the error is not find:
    NSMutableURLRequest *req;
    req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:30.0];
    if (![NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req]) {
        // Handle the error
        NSLog(@"");
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check URL just do a `HEAD` request using a `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I think of is to ping the URL, thought NSURLConnection can do that too (And actually any ping process should be based on NSURLConnection).
You can use this [open-source](https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper) for that.

Hope this answer satisfies you.